Should the language code be specified in the URL?
Is the correct version of the page for Norwegian speaking users from Norway to be https://test/no/catalogue or https://test/nb-no/catalogue?

It doesn't matter if you use "no" or "nb-no", as long as the same page in different languages has an unique URL for each language. If all pages are Norwegian you don't need to have the language in the URL, but it is always nice to indicate in the HTML what the language of the document is.

Depends on other languages you are using. But for Norwegian lang I would choose this https://test/no/catalogue. More human friendly. Also check hreflang.
